# Devolver el valor de una variable capturada de una funcion click

Tags: javascript

Tengo este html:

```js
function() {
  var resultado;

  var a = $('div p').click(function(data) {

    var i = $(this).prev().prev().before($('span')).text();
    resultado = i;

  });

  return resultado;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <p class="subscription-header" style="font-size: 0.9em"><img src="/micuentamovil/appicon/219/46" /><a href="url">Text1</a><br /><span style="position: relative; top: -5px; font-size: 0.9em">Description</span>
  </p>
  <p class="banner"><img src="/url" />
  </p>
  <p class="link"><a href="url">Text2 >></a>
  </p>
  <p class="divider"></p>
  <p class="actionlink-double">
    <a href="url">option1</a>
    <a href="url">option2</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Me gustaría devolver en un return Text1 cuando he hecho click en Text2. Estoy intentando esto pero no funciona:

**Añadido**

Perdonar por el retraso, efectivamente, lo que estoy buscando es cuando pulsas en Text2 >> devolver en una variable el valor del texto de Text1, es decir en este caso Text1.. siento no haber sido claro. Hasta ahora consigo que en console.log o una alert aparece el texto pero no consigo devolverlo en el return de la funcion global

Comment: ¿devolver que de text1? ¿el html de la url? ¿la imagen de arriba? ¿el texto? Tienes muchisimos fallos en las etiquetas. Dale una vuelta y mirate [ask]

Comment: El Texto, gracias

Comment: ¿para que son las option?¿Entonces clicar el link donde pone texto dos te hara una alerta por ejemplo de la "description"?

Comment: @Luis un saludo, por favor usa la opción [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/106833/edit) para agregar actualizaciones a tu pregunta. Es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y además obtienes tu primera medalla. Además 

es **muy importante revisar [ask]** que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma 

obtengas buenas respuestas, saludos y suerte!.

Answer (score 0):

Para selecionar uno puedes usar los selectores :odd, :even, :fisrt, [aqui mas ejemplos](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) todo dependera de lo que queires lograr

```js
function myFunction() {
     var text = $('.subscription-header a:first').text();
  return text;
}

$('.link a').on('click', function(e) {
 alert(myFunction());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <p class="subscription-header" style="font-size: 0.9em"><img src="/micuentamovil/appicon/219/46" /><a href="url">Text1</a><br /><span style="position: relative; top: -5px; font-size: 0.9em">Description</span>
  </p>
    <p class="subscription-header" style="font-size: 0.9em"><img src="/micuentamovil/appicon/219/46" /><a href="url">Text1</a><br /><span style="position: relative; top: -5px; font-size: 0.9em">Description</span>
  </p>
    <p class="subscription-header" style="font-size: 0.9em"><img src="/micuentamovil/appicon/219/46" /><a href="url">Text1</a><br /><span style="position: relative; top: -5px; font-size: 0.9em">Description</span>
  </p>
  <p class="banner"><img src="/url" />
  </p>
  <p class="link"><a href="#">Text2 >></a>
  </p>
  <p class="divider"></p>
  <p class="actionlink-double">
    <a href="url">option1</a>
    <a href="url">option2</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Lo que el SO esta pidiendo a lo que yo entiendo es que cuando clicas text2 devuelva el description bajo el text1. Pero creo que deberiamos esperar a mas información. Yo llevo una hora con código preparado a ver que dice.

Comment: Perdonar por el retraso, efectivamente, lo que estoy buscando es cuando pulsas en <p class="link"><a href="url">Text2 >></a></p> devolver en una variable el valor del texto de <a href="url">Text1</a>, es decir en este caso Text1.. siento no haber sido claro. Hasta ahora consigo que en console.log o una alert aparece el texto pero no consigo devolverlo en el return de la funcion global

Comment: Hice otro ejemplo por si es eso lo que buscas

Comment: Hola Luis, donde esta el ejemplo que hiciste que no logro  verlo

Comment: Este que estas comentando

Comment: Hola, efectivamente tu funcion me almacena el texto por lo que gracias a ti ya he avanzado bastante, el problema es que en esa pagina hay varios $('.subscription-header a').text(); y me los devuelve todos y la idea es

Comment: Quieres que sea uno en especifico?

Comment: asi es, justamente el que hace click

Comment: Ya esta editada de nuevo

Comment: Alguna idea como la funcion de arriba devolveria solo la informacion del elemento que se hace click..gracias

Comment: pero es que estas haciendo click en el que tiene clase link, entonces alli me pierdo con lo que quieres lograr,

Answer (score 0):

Solo identifica las posiciones de los enlaces, el link a actuar está dentro del contenedor `.link` y el link a extraer el texto dentro de `.subscription-header`. Por último, evita que se realice la acción por defecto en cuanto se haga click en el link (redirección) deteniendo esta acción por medio de `preventDefault`.

**Ejemplo**

```js
var text = '';
$('.link a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // si no pones esto te redirige
  text = $('.subscription-header a').text();
  // ahora ya puedes usar text en otro lado
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <p class="subscription-header" style="font-size: 0.9em"><img src="/micuentamovil/appicon/219/46" /><a href="url">Text1</a><br /><span style="position: relative; top: -5px; font-size: 0.9em">Description</span>
  </p>
  <p class="banner"><img src="/url" />
  </p>
  <p class="link"><a href="url">Text2 >></a>
  </p>
  <p class="divider"></p>
  <p class="actionlink-double">
    <a href="url">option1</a>
    <a href="url">option2</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por  tu ayuda pero mi pregunta es porque el return de esa funcion siempre es indefinido aun declarando la variable como global:

Comment: function() {
 
$('.link a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // 
   var text = $('.subscription-header a').text();
  console.log(text);
});
  return text;

}

Comment: Es normal que suceda, es un concepto clave llamado asincronía. Los callbacks **no se ejecutan secuencialmente con el resto del código**, si no en paralelo. Esto causa que cuando se lea el `return` el callback recién se esté ejecutando.

Comment: Y no hay forma entonces de devolver el valor en el return que es el objetivo inicial..gracias

Comment: @Luis No tienes por qué devolverlo, ese es el punto. Estás dentro de un evento, si retornas ese valor no habrá ninguna variable declarada por ti que reciba ese valor a retornar. Lo correcto es **asignar** el valor dentro del listener; si quieres puedes agregar más listeners que se ejecutarán secuencialmente.

Comment: Ahi es donde me pierdo, por mucho que llevo analizandolo no se como asignar el valor dentro del listener.. pero muchas gracias por el soporte

Comment: Sigo sin entender como puedo aplicar un listener para guardar el valor en una variabel

Comment: @Luis simplemente declara la variable **fuera del listener** y cuando se ejecute el listener el valor será guardado en la variable. Al guardarlo fuera del listener haces que la variable sea **global**. PD: esa función que engloba el listener es innecesaria.

Comment: Debido a que no controlo mucho ya que llevo pocos meses me podrías indicar con el ejemplo que puse como sería..gracias

Comment: @Luis con mucho gusto. He editado mi respuesta para que se adapte a tu pedido.

Comment: Muchas gracias, está noche mismo lo pruebo

Comment: Hola, efectivamente tu funcion me almacena el texto por lo que gracias a ti ya he avanzado bastante, el problema es que en esa pagina hay varios $('.subscription-header a').text(); y me los devuelve todos y la idea es que devuelva solo donde se hace click, por cierto aun no me aclaro muy bien en el foro por lo que disculpar mis fallos de organización y muchas gracias

Comment: @Luis lo mejor en ese caso es agregar identificadores a los links con los que quieres trabajar.